# Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted in asp.net web application

Tags: c#

When i tried to run my asp.net web application ,i got this error-Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
-but when i change the port then it works fine

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        static readonly object _lock = new object();
        static readonly Dictionary<int, TcpClient> list_clients = new Dictionary<int, TcpClient>();
        TcpListener ServerSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int count = 1;
            ServerSocket.Start();            
            TcpClient client = ServerSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
            if(client.Connected)
            {
                lock (_lock) list_clients.Add(count, client);
                Console.WriteLine("Someone connected!!");

                Thread t = new Thread(handle_clients);
                t.Start(count);
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                ServerSocket.Stop();
            }                               

        }

        public static void handle_clients(object o)
        {
            int id = (int)o;
            TcpClient client;
            Service1 service1 = new Service1();
            Console.WriteLine("Calling Web Methods");
            string dataa = service1.HelloWorld("Hi hello");
            lock (_lock) client = list_clients[id];
            //int count = 1;
            if (client.Connected)
            {
                broadcast(dataa);
            }
            else
            {
                lock (_lock) list_clients.Remove(id);
                client.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                client.Close();
            }

        }

        public static void broadcast(string data)
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data + Environment.NewLine);

            lock (_lock)
            {
                foreach (TcpClient c in list_clients.Values)
                {
                    NetworkStream stream = c.GetStream();

                    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```